# Apache2: Rewrite Rules won't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm seriously struggling with these rewrite rules. No matter what I try they just wont work.

The module is loaded and something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
```

Works perfectly while something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^board/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([^.]+)$ board.php?id=$1
```

Which should make board.php?b=XYZ to board/XYZ

No matter what I search, nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the current behavior is, although it's the wrong querystring to match `b=`:

```
board.php?id=$1
```

The problem is `id != b` — it should be:

```
board.php?b=$1
```

So you could probably do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?b=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is fine but the regex pattern you are using te test the uri is wrong.

If you want to rewrite **/board/XYZ** to **/board.php?b=XYZ** you can use the following rule in **root/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^board/(.+)$ /board.php?b=$1 [L,NC]
```